# How to style a button that displays as an image

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following code:

```css
#a img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14em;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 14em;
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<button id='a' name='a' value='x'><img src='../../files/images/someimage.png'  alt='text'></button>
```

This displays my image inside a grey box like a button. Is there a way to get ride of the grey box around it?
As I just want to display the image with the same functions as a button

Any help welcome

Comment: you don't necessarily need the button. You can just use Javascript to handle a "click" event on the image tag and do whatever you would have previously done via the button click. Otherwise, I think some CSS on the button to remove any border, background colour and padding on it should pretty much hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, you just need to remove default properties of `button`

```css
#a{
  background:none;
  border:0;
  outline:0;
}
```

```html
<button id='a' name='a' value='x'><img src='../../files/images/someimage.png' alt='text'></button>
```

Comment: Thats fantastic just what i was looking for, will accept answer as soon as I can. MAGIC

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, happy coding 

Answer (score 1):

```html
<button id='a' name='a' value='x'><img src='submit.gif'  alt='text'></button>
  <style>
  button{
    background:transparent;
    border:none
  }
  <style>
```

You can specify background transparent for the button. If you want you can use   input type="image" .

Answer (score 1):

```css
button {
  background: url("http://placehold.it/200x50");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
border: thin solid red;
}
```

```html
<button></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do via `border:none`. Just add it to your css

```
#a { display:inline-block; width:14em; margin-left:3%;  margin-top:20px; float:left; border: none; outline: 0; background: none }
#a:focus, #a:hover { border: none; outline: 0; background: none }
```